# Allure-report empty when allure-results have multiple result folders

Tags: python, pytest, reporting, nose, allure

The allure-results folders is in the following structure.

```
allure-results/
|-- assertions1
|   |-- 2f429779-3c86-4958-8e8b-e9a03a25cd20-attachment.txt
|   |-- 312890b7-fd56-4c65-bee9-14d76ff4a58e-testsuite.xml
|   |-- 3f385845-14cc-4411-86c2-06e35a76b2ad-attachment.txt
|   |-- 59f04042-8f20-4c11-b611-b5364e892556-attachment.txt
|   |-- 8829ef83-06d2-425d-b5c6-dc2e09b8b3b2-attachment.svg
|   `-- e37938ed-0c9b-4ac4-99d5-0e80f240a79e-attachment.txt
|-- assertions2
|   |-- 0adb3f17-3e46-48e3-bdc9-9603b6d31084-attachment.txt
|   |-- 0fd3980a-d55b-49b8-8bdd-c56b7282008d-attachment.txt
|   |-- 20f132d1-8b4d-453c-9cea-53c7f59ff12e-attachment.svg
|   |-- 2ed67517-f700-4cac-85f3-93aac1529828-attachment.txt
|   |-- 45246942-4479-468a-bf29-72f2f19dfce9-testsuite.xml
|   |-- 80b5e955-6cc3-4ce6-a954-ce46f554b810-attachment.txt
|   |-- a01f2abf-52fa-47ff-99c0-a43a5bd0756b-attachment.txt
|   |-- ce094c0b-256a-4bf6-92b3-17d2fadff3ca-attachment.txt
|   |-- e95eedf9-0d8f-49d6-8fd6-c02d4e1181bd-attachment.txt
|   `-- f7891f5d-e115-4031-a56a-203bb2f73d38-attachment.txt
|-- environment.xml
|-- assertions3
|   |-- c052da82-213b-4db2-8a33-7e96e501907c-testsuite.xml
|   `-- fd72c264-f037-4a02-b797-5407dd50a297-attachment.txt
|-- assertions4
|   |-- 8d8df3dd-47e1-416e-acb7-6ef62d529c0f-attachment.txt
|   `-- c2dadf11-fcbc-4027-97bc-98849be24540-testsuite.xml
|-- assertions5
|   |-- ea11687b-7846-4bbb-923c-8cc62f7c69b5-attachment.txt
|   `-- f24ddf31-a3f8-4feb-bf07-ba6465ee4555-testsuite.xml
`-- assertions6
    |-- 08d24268-a755-4969-aa3b-5660951fd21d-testsuite.xml
    `-- 6b4590bf-4df7-4e39-941e-63e1f902968a-attachment.txt
```

We can see that there are multiple testsuite results in it along with environment.xml.

I am trying to generate an allure report for it. Latest allurecommandline is installed.

When I try to run the following command, the allure report is empty.

`allure generate allure-results/`

It works when I give an individual result directory.

`allure generate allure-results/assertions1`

I am looking for a way to make allure generate a report based on all the testsuite results folders present in the allure-results.

The testsuite results are generated using python nosetests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create subdirectories. Every file should be in the `allure-results` directory (without subdirectories). For that reason, the files have random file names.
Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution.

I used the following and it worked.

`allure generate allure-results/*`

Note: In order to get the environment.xml to be parsed by the allure, move it to another folder inside the results. I moved it to "allure-results/environment/environment.xml".

Comment: using allure generate allure-results/* I can only see data for history and duration trend, retry trend and trend and nothing else